# How can I stop the page from snapping back to its original position

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have implemented a ScrollViewer around the content panel grid in my Windows Phone 7 page. However, whenever I try and scroll down to the bottom of the page, it snaps right back to it's original position the moment I take my finger off the screen. In other words on scrolling it does not retain it's last position rendering the scroll pointless.

This is my page code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71" x:Class="StepsForWater.Views.Submit"
                        mc:Ignorable="d"
                        d:DesignWidth="480"
                        d:DesignHeight="696"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                        SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                        Orientation="Portrait"
                        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
                        DataContext="{Binding Submit, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<!-- Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbar_About" IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="About" Click="appbar_About_Click"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbar_WalkRun" IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Walk/Run" Click="appbar_WalkRun_Click"/>            
        <!--<shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuItem1" Text="MenuItem 1"></shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuItem2" Text="MenuItem 2"></shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>-->
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/StepsForWater;component/Images/submit-bg.png" />
    </Grid.Background>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,28">

        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"
                   Text="MY APPLICATION"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle"
                   Text="page name"
                   Margin="9,-7,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />-->
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->        
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,-241" Background="{x:Null}">            
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,57,0,0" x:Name="tBlk_Username" Text="{Binding UserName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,79,0,0" x:Name="tb_UserNameVal" Text="{Binding UserNameValue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="423" />
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,169,0,0" x:Name="tBlk_Email" Text="{Binding Email}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,278,0,0" x:Name="tBlk_Message" Text="{Binding Message}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,191,0,0" x:Name="tb_EmailVal" Text="{Binding EmailValue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="423" />
        <TextBox Height="153" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,300,0,0" x:Name="tb_MessageVal" Text="{Binding MessageValue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="423" />
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Location}" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,459,0,0" x:Name="chk_Location" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="{Binding Submit}" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,761,0,0" x:Name="btn_Submit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="SubmitClick" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>            
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,540,0,0" Name="tBlk_PicInfo" Text="{Binding PictureInfo}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,583,0,0" Name="img_FlickrPic" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
        <Button Content="Capture" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,0,0,138" Name="btn_Capture" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="160" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="CaptureClick" Command="{Binding CaptureCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
        </Grid>                        
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Update: Fixed my problem, all I needed to do was to ensure that my scrollviewer's height was less than that of it's contained grid!

Comment: What's with all the height and margins? you should be using Grids with Row/Column definitions/StackPanels. I don't think having the margin of anything be -241 a good idea.

Comment: I haven't really focused on the layout at all, All i've done is thrown controls on a design surface inside the content panel grid that is available in the OOTB template. All that formatting is just generated code based on my placement of those controls one below the other. Apparently the designer just generates horrible code :). I haven't touched the xaml manually except to add the ScrollViewer. It's a sandbox application really.

Comment: @Cranialsurge Check out my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others you should probably rethink the way your making your layout. There are cleaner options. But to answer your question, there were two problems. The first is that you need to specify a Height on the ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="760">
....
</ScrollViewer>
```

The second problem is the negative margin of 241 you have applied to the grid. Simply take that off. It's preventing anything within that range of being scrolled to.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
....
</Grid>
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I definitely need to learn more about layouts. I just plop stuff on the page right now since I'm pretty new to XAML/Silverlight based UI dev. in general.